# How to change fontawsome icon onclick

Tags: javascript

I have this code which should change the fontawsome icon onclick but it's not working, I tried it with a picture and it worked but when using font awsome it doesn't. Please help.

```
<script>
  var icon = document.getElementById("icon");
icon.onclick = function(){
        document.body.classList.toggle("darkTheme");
        if(document.body.classList.contains("darkTheme")){
            icon.classList.remove('far fa-moon');
            icon.classList.add('fas fa-sun fa-lg');
            /*icon.src = "img/sun.png";*/
            localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
        }
        else{
            icon.classList.remove('fas fa-sun fa-lg');
            icon.classList.add('far fa-moon');
            /*icon.src = "img/moon.png";*/
            localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
        }
        
    }
</script>
```

Comment: "It's not working" doesn't help us. Have you debugged your code using the (F12) devtools? Are there any errors? You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to **separate** classes by **comma**, dont use **space**

```js
icon.classList.remove('far', 'fa-moon');
icon.classList.add('fas', 'fa-sun', 'fa-lg');
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work at adding the classes you need to the element. Also it is cleaner to use an event listener to keep JS CSS HTML separated.
And as @Ali Yaghoby mentioned you need to separate each class with a comma

```
const icon = document.getElementById('icon');
    
    icon.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
    
    if(document.body.classList.contains("darkTheme")){
                icon.classList.remove('far', 'fa-moon');
                icon.classList.add('fas', 'fa-sun', 'fa-lg');
                
                localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
            }
            else{
                icon.classList.remove('fas', 'fa-sun', 'fa-lg');
                icon.classList.add('far', 'fa-moon')
                
                localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
            }
            
        });
```